# is there a way to make JQuery animation functions blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery animation functions are non-blocking, but i'm looking for a way to make them blocking. For example i want something like this:

```
$("#btn").fadeOut(1000);
console.log("fadeOut() Completed..");
```

One solution I have found in other answers is to use callbacks, so this can be achieved using a callback function like this:

```
$("#btn").fadeOut(1000, function () {
    console.log("fadeOut() Completed..");
});
```

But i'm looking for a different solution (if possible) to make the call to `fadeOut` function blocking, i.e, when i call `fadeOut(1000)`, the next line of code should not be executed until the fadeOut function is completed.

Comment: the callback method is perfect for this. It's the reason the callback parameter was created. Any reason why you don't want to use it?

Comment: yes the callback method is perfect, actually i'm working on a legacy code and previously i was just removing the element (no animation), but now in some cases the animation is based on a flag, the issue is that the code logic is dependent on removal of the element and i can't simply move everything in callback that will complicate things.. the solution is possible with callback but with much more effort.

Comment: @AbubakarAzeem, Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov, I still haven't found a solution for this, currently I have solved my problem using callbacks, but I would like to find a solution for this as it will really simplify the code in my case (may be for others in the future). One solution I have in mind is if we can have a custom implementation of the `fadeOut` function (may be using custom sleep) to achieve this?

Comment: @AbubakarAzeem, If your problem is using asynchronous functions for IE, then use babel - https://babeljs.io/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't make the animation functions blocking.

You can use the callback method you've discovered.

If you're in an environment where you can use `async` functions, it's not awfully hard to promisify the callback, and then do something like `await fadeOutP("#btn", 1000)`:

```
function fadeOutP(selector, time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => $(selector).fadeOut(time, resolve));
}
// buttons fade out in sequence:
async function thing() {
  await fadeOutP("#btn1", 1000);
  await fadeOutP("#btn2", 1000);
  await fadeOutP("#btn3", 1000);
}
```

Comment: `async` is not supported in IE so that cannot be used in my case :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use method `promise()`.

> The **.promise()** method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended.

[Read more.](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```js
$("#btn").fadeOut(1000);
$("#btn").promise().done(function () {
      console.log("fadeOut() Completed..");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">button</button>
```